# Traditional method won’t work in factorizing a homogeneous cyclic expression

Tags: polynomials

When I come across the problem (#464874)

[Factorize $ a^2(b − c)^3 + b^2(c − a)^3 + c^2(a − b)^3$],

I start off with the following solution:-

E = The given expression, which is homogeneous and cyclic in a, b and c, and is of degree 5.

p = (a - b)(b - c)(c - a) is cyclic of degree 3.

If E = p.q, then q should be homogeneous and cyclic in a, b and c, and is of degree 2.

The most general expression of q is then $m(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + n(ab + bc + ca)$; for some m and n.

Thus, $E = (a - b)(b - c)(c - a)[m(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + n(ab + bc + ca)]$

m and n can be obtained by comparing coefficients, (according to the traditional method).

To my surprise, it won’t work in this case.

I notice that, in the expanded form of E, the terms of the form $(+/-) 3 a^2 b^2 c^1$ are all cancelled out leaving terms having the form $a^2 b^3 c^0$ behind.

As an example, if I compare the coefficients of $ a^2 b^3 c^0$ , I have [1 = - m + n]

The above will be the same if I use other terms like  $ - a^2 c^3 b^0$. Thus, it leaves me with 2 unknowns but actually one equation only.

Maybe I have overlook something, Please comment!

Of course, as a last resort, I can still substitute two different sets of values for a, b, c and get m = 0 and n = 1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this by comparing the coefficients .
For example by comparing the coefficient of $a^4 $:
$$(a)(-a)(ma^2)= -ma^4$$
but there is no term with $a^4$ thus $m=0$ .
And as you said by comparing the coefficient of $a^2b^3$ we get $n-m=1$ that is $n=1$ (since $m=0$)

Comment: I have just learnt something new, which is 'comparing coefficients of not-existing terms'. Thanks.